# How can I improve the speed of QTextEdit::setPlainText() in QT?

Tags: c++, qt

I am recently writing a [TextEditor project](https://github.com/JosanSun/textEditor) uplaoded in the Github. The project has finished with the basic function of plain text editor!

However, I cannot be satisfied with the speed of opening a big file.

For example, when opening 540KB file, the cost of `readAll()` is 18ms, but the cost of `setPlainText()` is **`42s`**, which is annoying. How can I improve my code performance? Can you give me some advice? Thanks in advance.

My main code is below:

```
// textedit.cpp 
#define qcout qDebug()
bool TextEditor::readFile(const QString &fileName)
{
    QFile file(fileName);
    if(!file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text))
    {
        QMessageBox::warning(this, tr("TextEditor"),
                             tr("Cannot read file %1.\n%2.")
                             .arg(file.fileName())
                             .arg(file.errorString()));
        return false;
    }

    //QTextStream inFile(&file);
#ifndef QT_NO_CURSOR
    QApplication::setOverrideCursor(Qt::WaitCursor);
#endif
    QTime t1, t2, t3, t4;
    t1 = QTime::currentTime();
    const QByteArray data = file.readAll();     // 18ms
    t2 = QTime::currentTime();
    qcout << t1.msecsTo(t2);
    QTextCodec::ConverterState state;
    QTextCodec *codec = QTextCodec::codecForName("UTF-8");
    const QString text = codec->toUnicode(data.constData(), data.size(), &state);
    //qcout << text;
    t3 = QTime::currentTime();
    qcout << t2.msecsTo(t3);
    if (state.invalidChars > 0)
    {
        // Not a UTF-8 text - using system default locale
        QTextCodec * codec1 = QTextCodec::codecForLocale();
        qcout << codec1->name();
        if (!codec1)
            return false;
        qcout << "invalidChars > 0";
        setPlainText(codec1->toUnicode(data));
    }
    else
    {
        qcout << "invalidChars = 0";
        setPlainText(text);
    }
    t4 = QTime::currentTime();
    qcout << t3.msecsTo(t4);              // 42s annoying!
#ifndef QT_NO_CURSOR
    QApplication::restoreOverrideCursor();
#endif
    return true;
}
```

The result is:

```
18
1
invalidChars = 0
42126
```

Comment: What programming language is this? Might want to retag your question.

Comment: @necko [Qt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qt_(software)) a cross-platform application framework using C++.

Comment: You might need to read the data as you do but then split it up into smaller chunks that can then be set as plain text in the widget. This way you might need to take scrolling/resizing/line breaks into account. Not sure if this is feasible.

Comment: `QTextEdit` is known to be slow due to its layouting capabilities. You might consider using other widgets for your text, for example `QPlainTextEdit`.

Comment: @vahancho It costs `32s` now, but still annoying...

Comment: What is the structure (encoding, character set, locale) of your test file? upload it to your repository.

Comment: @MohammadKanan I have uploaded my test file in the testFile folder. Its name is **longline.txt**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The name of the test file tells the story already (*longline.txt*).

The performance penalty is due to the default word wrap mode (**QTextOption::WrapAtWordBoundaryOrAnywher**e), which tries to wrap words without cutting them in half.

Since your file is basically a very long single "word", the poor QTextEdit has no choice but to **scan the whole file** looking for the end of it.

If you add this line in the constructor:

```
setWordWrapMode(QTextOption::WrapAnywhere);
```

you can override the default wrap mode. When **QTextOption::WrapAnywhere** is set, wrapping can occur at any point on a line (check the documentation [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextoption.html#WrapMode-enum)).

Just for reference, doing so my machine took only 199 ms to load the file and display it.

However, since this is a very unusual text case, I would suggest you to test your application with real world examples, or at the least expose the wrap mode settings to the user via the UI.

Comment: My result of test is about 1000ms. Thank you. The result is acceptable.